# ng-bind-html not working with TranslateJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am implementing a translation on a web application using angularJS and a repository named angular-translate found on https://angular-translate.github.io/.
According to the documentation i could use this repository to set a text to a given element on the html.
I wanted to show a popup with a message in case the user haven't filled some textfields. For example: if i haven't filled the "name" and the "address" it would show a popup written: "Please fill the following fields: name, address".
However, using the ng-bind-html does not show the results that i desired.

The following atempts does not work as desired:

```
//Var1:'Name is not valid'
//Var2:'Invalid address'
dialog.msg = '<div translate>Var1</div><div translate>Var2</div>';
$scope.thisCanBeusedInsideNgBindHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml(dialog.msg);
$rootScope.showNotificationDialog('error', 'Atenção', dialog.msg);

//showNotificationDialog
<div class="text" ng-bind-html="dialog.msg"></div>
//Result: Var1
          Var2
<div class="text">{{dialog.msg}}</div>

//Result: <div translate>Var1</div><div translate>Var2</div>
```

I want the result to be:

Name is not valid
Invalid address

How can i achive this?

Answer (score 0):

For those who faced similar problems, divide the string and use the ng-repeat to simply pass the variables

```
<div ng-repeat="msg in dialog.msg">
        <div translate>{{msg}}</div>
    </div>
```